# How to use ExceptT to replace lots of IO (Either a b)

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monads, monad-transformers

I have a function which connects to a database, then runs a query. Each of these steps results in `IO (Either SomeErrorType SomeResultType)`.

One of the things I have really liked about using `Either` and similar monads in learning Haskell has been the ability to use the monad functions like `>>=` and combinators like `mapLeft` to streamline a  lot of the handling of expected error states.

My expectation here from reading blog posts, the `Control.Monad.Trans` documentation, and other answers on SO is that I have to somehow use transformers / lift to move from the `IO` context to the `Either` context.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52016583/907981) in particular is really good, but I'm struggling to apply it to my own case.

A simpler example of my code:

```
simpleVersion :: Integer -> Config -> IO ()
simpleVersion id c = 
  connect c >>= \case 
      (Left e)     -> printErrorAndExit e
      (Right conn) -> (run . query id $ conn)
              >>= \case 
                    (Left e)  -> printErrorAndExit e
                    (Right r) -> print r
                                   >> release conn
```

My problem is that (a) I'm not really understanding the mechanics of how `ExceptT` gets me to a similar place to the `mapLeft handleErrors $ eitherErrorOrResult >>= someOtherErrorOrResult >>= print` world; (b) I'm not sure how to ensure that the connection is always released in the nicest way (even in my simple example above), although I suppose I would use the [bracket pattern](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bracket_pattern).

I'm sure every (relatively) new Haskeller says this but I still really don't understand monad transformers and everything I read (except aforelinked SO answer) is too opaque for me (yet).

How can I transform the code above into something which removes all this nesting and error handling?

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831992/the-usage-of-monad-transformers/46833365#46833365)

Comment: You might also like [How do I deal with many levels of indentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33005903/791604).

Comment: Also related, but about `MaybeT` instead of `ExceptT`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579133/simplest-non-trivial-monad-transformer-example-for-dummies-iomaybe One note about `bracket` from base: it works on plain `IO` actions instead of `IO` actions "decorated" with transformers. One possible approach would be using `ExceptT` to avoid the nested `case`s, then using `runExceptT` to get back to an `IO` action, and wrapping that resulting action with `bracket`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's very enlightening to look at the source for the `Monad` instance of `ExceptT`:

```
newtype ExceptT e m a = ExceptT (m (Either e a))

instance (Monad m) => Monad (ExceptT e m) where
    return a = ExceptT $ return (Right a)
    m >>= k = ExceptT $ do
        a <- runExceptT m
        case a of
            Left e -> return (Left e)
            Right x -> runExceptT (k x)
```

If you ignore the `newtype` wrapping and unwrapping, it becomes even simpler:

```
m >>= k = do
    a <- m
    case a of
        Left e -> return (Left e)
        Right x -> k x
```

Or, as you seem to prefer not using `do`:

```
m >>= k = m >>= \a -> case a of
    Left e -> return (Left e)
    Right x -> k x
```

Does that chunk of code look familiar to you? The only difference between that and your code is that you write `printErrorAndExit` instead of `return . Left`! So, let's move that `printErrorAndExit` out to the top-level, and simply be happy *remembering* the error for now and not printing it.

```
simpleVersion :: Integer -> Config -> IO (Either Err ())
simpleVersion id c = connect c >>= \case (Left e)     -> return (Left e)
                                         (Right conn) -> (run . query id $ conn)
                                                          >>= \case (Left e)  -> return (Left e)
                                                                    (Right r) -> Right <$> (print r
                                                          >> release conn)
```

Besides the change I called out, you also have to stick a `Right <$>` at the end to convert from an `IO ()` action to an `IO (Either Err ())` action. (More on this momentarily.)

Okay, let's try substituting our `ExceptT` bind from above for the `IO` bind. I'll add a `'` to distinguish the `ExceptT` versions from the `IO` versions (e.g. `>>=' :: IO (Either Err a) -> (a -> IO (Either Err b)) -> IO (Either Err b)`).

```
simpleVersion id c = connect c >>=' \conn -> (run . query id $ conn)
                                             >>=' \r -> Right <$> (print r
                                             >> {- IO >>! -} release conn)
```

That's already an improvement, and some whitespace changes make it even better. I'll also include a `do` version.

```
simpleVersion id c =
    connect c >>=' \conn ->
    (run . query id $ conn) >>=' \r ->
    Right <$> (print r >> release conn)

simpleVersion id c = do
    conn <- connect c
    r <- run . query id $ conn
    Right <$> (print r >> release conn)
```

To me, that looks pretty clean! Of course, in `main`, you'll still want to `printErrorAndExit`, as in:

```
main = do
    v <- runExceptT (simpleVersion 0 defaultConfig)
    either printErrorAndExit pure v
```

Now, about that `Right <$> (...)`... I said I wanted to convert from `IO a` to `IO (Either Err a)`. Well, this kind of thing is why the `MonadTrans` class exists; let's look at its implementation for `ExceptT`:

```
instance MonadTrans (ExceptT e) where
    lift = ExceptT . liftM Right
```

Well, `liftM` and `(<$>)` are the same function with different names. So if we ignore the `newtype` wrapping and unwrapping, we get

```
lift m = Right <$> m
```

! So:

```
simpleVersion id c = do
    conn <- connect c
    r <- run . query id $ conn
    lift (print r >> release conn)
```

You could also choose to use `liftIO` if you like. The difference is that `lift` always lifts a monadic action up through exactly one transformer, but works for any pair of wrapped type and transformer type; while `liftIO` lifts an `IO` action up through as many transformers as necessary for your monad transformer stack, but only works for `IO` actions.

Of course, so far we've elided all the `newtype` wrapping and unwrapping. For `simpleVersion` to be as beautiful as it is in our last example here, you'd need to change `connect` and `run` to include those wrappers as appropriate.

Comment: It took me some time to fully get to grips with this but thank you for a really excellent answer. A quick follow-up question: how would you incorporate something like `bracket` to ensure the connection is always closed? Do I need to break the `ExceptT` which covers the `connect` call out into `IO (Either ConnectionError Connection)` so that I can handle the left case?

Comment: @GTF Got it in one!

Comment: And something like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-ext? It feels like there must be a common way of doing bracket-like things over ExceptT?

Comment: @GTF `MonadBaseControl` is a little controversial, but it will probably get you where you need to go for simple cases like this.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll read Snoyman's tutorial on it (https://www.yesodweb.com/book/monad-control)

Comment: @GTF ...just to be clear: the link you posted is a `MonadBaseControl` one. That's why I talked about it; not because I endorse that approach myself (I don't).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237573/discussion-between-gtf-and-daniel-wagner).

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with everything that @Daniel Wagner wrote. But there is another option how to organize work with `IO (Either err a)`.

There is function `try :: Exception e => IO a -> IO (Either e a)`, can we implement inverted version of it (`untry :: Exception e => IO (Either e a) -> IO a`)? Let's do that:

```
untry :: Exception e => IO (Either e a) -> IO a
untry action = action >>= either throwIO pure
```

Similar function is in package [unliftio](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio) named [fromEitherM](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-0.2.20/docs/UnliftIO-Exception.html#v:fromEitherM).

Now we can redesign your example:

```
simpleVersion :: Integer -> Config -> IO ()
simpleVersion id c = do
    conn <- untry . connect $ c
    r <- untry . run . query id $ conn
    print r
    release conn
```

For this trick to work, the error type needs to be instance of the [Exception](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:Exception) class.

`printErrorAndExit` is not used here because it should be done at the top level (`main` or near it). And there is possible to handle errors with functions such as `catch`, `try`.

The only problem left is that the connection can be not released if an error occurs between opening and closing it. Let's fix that with `bracket`:

```
simpleVersion :: Integer -> Config -> IO ()
simpleVersion id c = bracket (untry $ connect c) release $ \conn -> do
    r <- untry $ run $ query id conn
    print r
```

You can write helper function for create connection:

```
withConn :: Config -> (Connection -> IO a) -> IO a
withConn c = bracket (untry $ connect c) release
```

and than:

```
simpleVersion id = flip withConn $ \conn -> do
    r <- untry $ run $ query id conn
    print r
```

Than you can thinking about to use `ReaderT Connection IO` for implicitly provide the connection to your queries. After that you code can looks like:

```
simpleVersion id conf = withConn conf $ do
    r <- run $ query id
    print r
```