# What is the difference between Option and OptionT?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

There are two modules in fp-ts:

1. [Option](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html)
2. [OptionT](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/OptionT.ts.html)

As the [Code Conventions](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/guides/code-conventions.html#what-a-t-suffix-means-eg-sequencet) chapter says

> However usually it means *T*ransformer like in “monad transformers” (e.g. OptionT, EitherT, ReaderT, StateT)

So what is a Transformer? And how do I know what import to use?

Examples are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let’s look at what [`Option`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html#option-type-alias) and [`OptionT`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/OptionT.ts.html#optiont-interface=) are.

```ts
export type Option<A> = None | Some<A>
/** @deprecated */
export interface OptionT<M, A> extends HKT<M, Option<A>> {}
```

`Option` is the base monad we are familiar with, which represents a `Some<A>` or `None`.

`OptionT<M, A>` is identical to `HKT<M, Option<A>>`. This interface is actually [deprecated](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/commit/0cc618a8c6b8703f7a11d54d6a5659ee1db2c268) — I’ll explain this more later. You can still however use the helper functions in the `OptionT` module without using the `OptionT` type.

You can think of `OptionT` like this (which sadly doesn’t compile due to TypeScript’s lack of higher kinded types):

```ts
type OptionT<M, A> = M<Option<A>>
```

`OptionT` is an example of a monad transformer. A monad transformer is a way to combine multiple monads together into a new monad so we can use `chain` (and other utility functions).

### Example

Let’s look at a (slightly contrived) example.

```ts
import * as Console from 'fp-ts/Console'
import * as IO from 'fp-ts/IO'
import * as O from 'fp-ts/Option'
import {pipe} from 'fp-ts/function'

type IOOption<A> = IO.IO<O.Option<A>> // our new monad
// You could think of IOOption<A> as OptionT<IO, A>

const getNumber: IOOption<number> = pipe(
  Console.log('getting number'),
  IO.map(() => O.some(42))
)

/** Returns None when the number is not divisible by 2. */
const half = (number: number): IOOption<number> =>
  pipe(
    Console.log('halving number'),
    IO.map(() => (number % 2 ? O.none : O.some(number / 2)))
  )
```

How do we put `half` and `getNumber` together? Initially, you might think of doing something like this:

```ts
const bad: IOOption<number> = pipe(getNumber, IO.chain(O.chain(half)))
//                                                             ~~~~
// Argument of type '(number: number) => IOOption<number>' is not
// assignable to parameter of type '(a: number) => Option<unknown>'.
```

However, this doesn’t work. `O.chain` accepts a function that returns an `Option`, not an `IOOption`. Additionally, `IO.chain` accepts a function that returns an `IO`, but `O.chain` returns a function that returns an `Option`. (For more information you could read up on how [monads don’t compose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7040844/8289918).)

The correct way to do this is:

```ts
const good = pipe(
  getNumber,
  IO.chain(O.fold(
    // If we get a None, return IO None
    () => IO.of(O.none),
    // If we get a Some(number), return half(number)
    half
  ))
)
```

This seems fine for this small example, but you can imagine this getting a little unwieldy when you chain more and more functions together:

```ts
pipe(
  foo,
  IO.chain(O.fold(() => IO.of(O.none), bar)),
  IO.chain(O.fold(() => IO.of(O.none), baz)),
  IO.chain(O.fold(() => IO.of(O.none), qux))
)
```

Fortunately, we have the `OptionT` module. Using the [`chain`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/OptionT.ts.html#chain) from this module, we can remove the `IO.chain(O.fold(() => IO.of(O.none), ...))` boilerplate:

```ts
import * as OT from 'fp-ts/lib/OptionT'

const better = pipe(getNumber, OT.chain(IO.Monad)(half))

const ioOptionChain = OT.chain(IO.Monad)
const alsoBetter = pipe(getNumber, ioOptionChain(half))
```

The type of `OT.chain` is this:

```ts
// chain :: Monad m => (a -> m (Option b)) -> m (Option a) -> m (Option b)
export declare function chain<M>(
  M: Monad<M>
): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => HKT<M, Option<B>>) => (ma: HKT<M, Option<A>>) => HKT<M, Option<B>>
// a bunch of other overloads omitted for brevity
```

You may have noticed that the approach we used with `good` can be generalised to any monad `M`:

```ts
M.chain(O.fold(() => M.of(O.none), fn))
```

This is why `OT.chain` accepts a `M: Monad<M>`: a monad instance such as `IO.Monad`, `Task.Monad`, `Either.Monad`, etc.

### Do I use `Option` or `OptionT`?

Use `Option` if you’re only dealing with *just* `Option`. Use `OptionT` if the `Option` is wrapped in some other type like `IO`, `Task`, `Array`, `Either`, etc.

### Why `OptionT` is deprecated

Recall that `OptionT<M, A>` is equivalent to `HKT<M, Option<A>>`. While you’ll see [`HKT`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/HKT.ts.html#hkt-interface) pop up in overloads for some utility functions, you probably won’t use it in your own types. For example, our `IOOption<A>` *isn’t* `HKT<'IO', A>` and is instead equivalent to `Kind<'IO', Option<A>>`.

However, [`Kind`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/HKT.ts.html#kind-type-alias=) only works for monads with 1 type parameter. For more type parameters, there’s `Kind2` (e.g. for `Either`), `Kind3` (e.g. for `ReaderEither`), and `Kind4` (e.g. for `StateReaderTaskEither`).

This is why there’s so many overloads for `OT.chain` and other similar functions:

```ts
export declare function chain<M extends URIS4   >(M: Monad4 <M   >): <A, S, R, E, B>(f: (a: A) => Kind4<M, S, R, E, Option<B>>) => (ma: Kind4<M, S, R, E, Option<A>>) => Kind4<M, S, R, E, Option<B>>
export declare function chain<M extends URIS3   >(M: Monad3 <M   >): <A,    R, E, B>(f: (a: A) => Kind3<M,    R, E, Option<B>>) => (ma: Kind3<M,    R, E, Option<A>>) => Kind3<M,    R, E, Option<B>>
export declare function chain<M extends URIS3, E>(M: Monad3C<M, E>): <A,    R,    B>(f: (a: A) => Kind3<M,    R, E, Option<B>>) => (ma: Kind3<M,    R, E, Option<A>>) => Kind3<M,    R, E, Option<B>>
export declare function chain<M extends URIS2   >(M: Monad2 <M   >): <A,       E, B>(f: (a: A) => Kind2<M,       E, Option<B>>) => (ma: Kind2<M,       E, Option<A>>) => Kind2<M,       E, Option<B>>
export declare function chain<M extends URIS2, E>(M: Monad2C<M, E>): <A,          B>(f: (a: A) => Kind2<M,       E, Option<B>>) => (ma: Kind2<M,       E, Option<A>>) => Kind2<M,       E, Option<B>>
export declare function chain<M extends URIS    >(M: Monad1 <M   >): <A,          B>(f: (a: A) => Kind <M,          Option<B>>) => (ma: Kind <M,          Option<A>>) => Kind <M,          Option<B>>
export declare function chain<M                 >(M: Monad  <M   >): <A,          B>(f: (a: A) => HKT  <M,          Option<B>>) => (ma: HKT  <M,          Option<A>>) => HKT  <M,          Option<B>>
```

The overload we actually used in `OT.chain(IO.Monad)` is the one with `Kind` in it (second last one).

This is why it doesn’t really make that much sense to use the `OptionT` type when it can only be used for the last overload with `HKT`.

---

If you would like to learn more about monad transformers:

- [‘Monad transformers’ on the Haskell wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers)
- [The usage of monad transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46831992/8289918) [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell)

Even though they’re about Haskell, the same principles apply to fp-ts.

Comment: Please recommend some articles about using fp-ts

Comment: @captain-yossarian Sorry for the late response! I haven’t read them but the author of fp-ts Giulio Canti has written some articles about using the library: https://dev.to/gcanti

Answer (score 1):

A Monad Transformer is a concept from functional programming in general. I'll defer to the Wikipedia definition because it seems pretty precise:

> In functional programming, a monad transformer is a type constructor which takes a monad as an argument and returns a monad as a result.
>
> Monad transformers can be used to compose features encapsulated by monads – such as state, exception handling, and I/O – in a modular way. Typically, a monad transformer is created by generalising an existing monad; applying the resulting monad transformer to the identity monad yields a monad which is equivalent to the original monad (ignoring any necessary boxing and unboxing).

-- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_transformer)

---

To help illustrate why this might be a nice set of utilities to create, let's look at the [`match`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/OptionT.ts.html#match) definition from the `OptionT` module.

```js
// It is overloaded a few time to support Functors with multiple type parameters
// but this is the simplest
export declare function match<F>(
  F: Functor<F>
): <B, A>(onNone: () => B, onSome: (a: A) => B) => (ma: HKT<F, Option<A>>) => HKT<F, B>
```

You would use this function if you have a `Functor` and want to be able to handle the case where that functor holds an `Option` value just a single time.

For example, if your `Functor` were an `Array` then you could use `match` like

```js
import * as A from 'fp-ts/Array';
import * as O from 'fp-ts/Option';
import { match } from 'fp-ts/OptionT';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/function';

const defaultTo0 = match(
  A.Functor,
)(
  () => 0,
  (a: number) => a,
);

const sum = pipe(
  [O.some(1), O.some(2), O.none, O.some(3)],
  defaultTo0,
  A.reduce(0, (acc, c) => acc + c),
);

console.log(sum); // 6
```

In this case, we use the `match` function from the option transformer module to create a helper that converts `Array<Option<number>>` into `Array<number>`. Monad Transformers are pretty broad subject so it's hard to say, "this is exactly when you use one" in more definite terms than what the Wikipedia article is saying. Hopefully this example provides a small example of how it might make managing multiple monadic layers a bit less tedious?

Comment: `defaultTo0` could also be defined as `getOrElse(A.Monad, 0)` (using `getOrElse` from `OptionT`).

Comment: Sure, this was just an example. To be honest I just picked a random helper and then tried to think of a use case. The question in general is a bit broad.